# SEO URL Redirection using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I want to know what is best SEO redirection, 301 or 302?

I want to redirect some URL to PayPal purchase page, What the best 301 or 302?

For example:

```
I want to redirect this link:
    http://example.com/?product_id=123
To PayPal purchase page:
https://www.paypal.com/xxxxxxxxetc...
```

301 or 302?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The rules have changed (at least for Google)**

It used to be 301 Redirection, but Google's John Mueller [announced](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC) in February 2016 that it doesn't matter anymore:

> **Do I lose "link juice" from the redirects?**
>
> No, for 301 or 302 redirects from HTTP to HTTPS no PageRank is lost.

## So what should I use?

Since the SEO doesn't matter, you should use the HTTP codes as advertised:

- 301 for permanent redirections
- 302 for temporarily redirections

For more info check out moz.com on [redirection rules for seo](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) where you'll also find this picture

[image]

Comment: You should use 301 if the redirect is permanent (i.e your paypal redirection is not just a temporary solution to a problem)

Comment: my links is temporary, because some link removed (not for sale) from my php script.

Comment: Then use 302 (temporary redirect)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com?product_id=$1 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.paypal.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Try this